# TypeScript / Import & Export of modules / classes - Runtime error when running imported class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using TypeScript.

I have inside file **String.ts** the following:

```
module Sgc.Sys {
    "use strict";
    export class String {       
        static trim(input: string): string {
            return input.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        };
//-- other methods below ...
    }
}
```

Then in file **Number.ts** (located in the same folder of String.ts) I use the method Sgc.Sys.String.trim() defined above:

```
module Sgc.Sys {
    "use strict";
    export class Number {

    static someMethod(input : string) : string {
            //-- some code
            var str = Sgc.Sys.String.trim(input);
            return str;

        };
    }
}
```

The problem: method trim of Sgc.Sys.String must be defined/called as above to be accepted withou errors by TypeScript; however when at runtime the Sgc.Sys.String is undefined and therefore Sgs.Sys.String.trim(input) fires exception.

What should I to be able to call Sgc.Sys.String.trim from inside Sgc.Sys.Number when both String.ts and Number.ts are in the same folder ..\Sgc\Sys ?

Thanks,
MG

Answer (score 2):

You must add a reference to the Number.ts file:

```
/// <reference path="String.ts" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error at runtime, you need to ensure you include both compiled JavaScript files on your page.

I have assumed you are not using module loading based on your code samples.

```
<script src="/Sgc/Sys/String.js"></script>
<script src="/Sgc/Sys/Number.js"></script>
```

Additional notes...

TypeScript targets ECMAScript 3 by default, so your "use strict" statments won't have any effect - you need to target ECMAScript 5 for this feature.